# how is the keyword "using" used in the following case in c++?

Tags: c++

Case 1:

```
using unumber = unsigned long;
unumber uvalue {};
```

Case 2:

```
using udigit_t = unsigned char; 
using ubigvalue_t = vector<udigit_t>; 
ubigvalue_t ubig_value;
```

Does `using` work in this case like an inferred type?

Comment: What is "this" case ? one or two ?

Comment: I was just trying to outline different cases where the keyword "using" is used

Comment: sorry, inferred type sounds better

Comment: Where would the inference be here?

Comment: Yes, my opinion doesn't make any sense, but I think @iehrlich cleared this up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `using` is another keyword for `typedef` (among other things) since C++11. Both of these are used to create a type aliases. Therefore,

```
using udigit_t = unsigned char;
```

and

```
typedef unsigned char udigit_t;
```

are equal expressions, which will allow you to use `udigit_t` in the same sense as if you wrote `unsigned char` instead (with some pitfalls). For more information, take a look here:

[Type alias, alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

Answer (score 1):

`using` can be used as an alternative to `typedef` for defining type aliases in C++11 (no C++03/98). In some cases it makes your code easier to look. Compare these examples.

```
typedef unsigned char byte, *pbyte, &rbyte;
using byte = unsigned char;
using pbyte = unsigned char*;
using rbyte = unsigned char &;

typedef int (*fun)(int, int);
using fun = int (*)(int, int);
// And when later...
fun f = [&](int a, int b){return a + b;};
```

In this case, `using` does **not** state an inferred type, but a clearly defined type. To let the compiler infer and decide the type of a variable, use `auto` (C++11 only). So you can write

```
auto f = [](){return 1;};
// No more need to write this below
int (*f)(void) = [](){return 1;};
```